# Add a total to aggregated sub-totals in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Let's say I have documents in my MongoDB collection that look like this:

```
{ name: "X", ...}
{ name: "Y", ...}
{ name: "X", ...}
{ name: "X", ...}
```

I can create a pipeline view using aggregation that shows sub-totals i.e.

```
$group: {
  _id: '$name',
  count: {
    $sum: 1
  }
}
```

which results in:

```
{ _id: "X",
  count: 3 },
{ _id: "Y",
  count: 1}
```

but how do I add a total in this view i.e.

```
{ _id: "X",
  count: 3 },
{ _id: "Y",
  count: 1},
{_id: "ALL",
 count: 4}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query1

- group to count
- union with the same collection, with pipeline to add the total count, in one extra document

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70584477-m)

```js
coll1.aggregate(
[{"$group":{"_id":"$name", "count":{"$sum":1}}},
 {"$unionWith":
  {"coll":"coll1",
   "pipeline":[{"$group":{"_id":"ALL", "count":{"$sum":1}}}]}}])
```

Query2

- without `$union` for MongoDB < 4.4
- group and count
- group by null and collect the documents, and total count
- add to `docs` array the extra document with the total count
- unwind and replace root to restore the structure

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70584477-1-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group":{"_id":"$name", "count":{"$sum":1}}},
 {"$group":
  {"_id":null, "docs":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}, "total":{"$sum":"$count"}}},
 {"$project":
  {"docs":
   {"$concatArrays":["$docs", [{"_id":"ALL", "count":"$total"}]]}}},
 {"$unwind":"$docs"},
 {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$docs"}}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Looks like we are running Mongo 4.2.9 and the `$unionWith` isn't available until 4.4. I will need to see if we can upgrade and try then. Thank you.

Comment: ok i didn't know i added one more query for MongoDB <4.4 without `$unionWith`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      count: { $count: {} }
    }
  },
  {
    $unionWith: {
      coll: "collection",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "ALL",
            count: { $count: {} }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KQuIsUrvDlO)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Looks like we are running Mongo 4.2.9 and the `$unionWith` isn't available until 4.4. I will need to see if we can upgrade and try then. Thank you.